# Check if Student is over 18

Tags: c++, class

I'm doing an homework that require me to check if the Student is over 18.
My function is this:

```
bool Student::isOverEighteen() {
  int date[3]; // D/M/Y
  char *pdata;

  pdata = strtok(Anagrafica::birth, "/"); // Anagrafica is the base class

  for (short i = 0; pdata != NULL; i++) {
    data[i] = pdata;
    pdata = strtok(NULL, "/");
  }

  time_t t    = time(NULL);
  tm *locale  = localtime(&t);

  if (data[0] < locale->tm_mday &&
     (data[1] < locale->tm_mon + 1  || data[1] == locale->tm_mon + 1) &&
     (locale->tm_year + 1900 - data[3] > 18))
  {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

However, when I display the date of birth it show me the date plus the classroom of the student. For example: 25/06/19944A (4A is the name of the classroom)

The function that I use to register students information:

```
Student::Student() {
  std::cout << "Name: ";
  std::cin.getline(Anagrafica::name, 101);
  std::cout << "Surname: ";
  std::cin.getline(Anagrafica::surname, 101);
  std::cout << "Birth (XX/XX/XXXX): ";
  std::cin.getline(Anagrafica::birth, 11);
  std::cout << "Classroom: ";
  std::cin.getline(Anagrafica::classroom, 101);
}
```

The function for displaying them:

```
void Anagrafica::Show() {
  std::cout << "\nName:" << this->name;
  std::cout << "\nSurname:" << this->surname;
  std::cout << "\nBirth:" << this->birth;
  std::cout << "\nClassroom: " << this->classroom;
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And they are declared:

```
char name[100];
char surname[100];
char birth[10];
char classroom[100];
```

Any solution for making this working?

EDIT (for Nik Bougalis):

Here is the one I use now.
The problems with strings started because I was using c_str; instead of c_str();

```
bool Entry::IsOverEighteen() {
  int date[3];

  date[0] = std::atoi(this->birth.substr(0, 2).c_str());  // Day
  date[1] = std::atoi(this->birth.substr(4, 2).c_str());  // Month
  date[2] = std::atoi(this->birth.substr(6, 4).c_str());  // Year

  time_t t  = time(NULL);
  tm *local = localtime(&t);

  // Perche' sia maggiorenne occorre che:
  //  Il giorno attuale sia maggiore di quello di nascita
  //  Il mese attuale sia maggiore o uguale a quello di nascita
  //  L' anno attuale - l' anno di nascita sia maggiore o uguale 18
  if (local->tm_mday > date[0] && 
     (local->tm_mon + 1 > date[1] || local->tm_mon + 1 == date[1]) && 
     (local->tm_year + 1900 - date[2] > 18 || local->tm_year + 1900 - date[2] == 18))
  {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is way too localized...

Comment: Should I write here the complete program?

Comment: @user1860848 no, you should narrow it down to a specific problem.

Comment: Don't use `char` arrays for strings in C++. Just... don't.

Comment: But if I use string, I can't find a way to convert the to int type.

Comment: You aren't converting it to an int type right now. You are just doing... stuff. The code you pasted here to convert the string into integers simply doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `char birth[10]` is exactly as long as the string **25/06/1994** (i.e. 10 bytes) leaving no space for the NULL terminator, so when printing out the `birth` string, cout starts reading, continues past the end of `birth` and onto `classroom`.

Also note that you consistently call `cin.getline` with a buffer size that is one *LARGER* than the actual buffer. You're in essence telling `getline`: "here's a 10 byte buffer... read 11 bytes into it!" Is that what you *really* mean?

All of this, of course, would not have happened if you used `std::string` instead of `char[]`. Why didn't you?

Now, as far as `isOverEighteen` is concerned: the function is *completely* broken, and in fact, the version you show here won't even compile. Let's see if we can go about fixing it.

My first question, of course, would be why not simply have the birthday input as 3 integers *directly* instead of accepting it as a string? But let's assume you can't for your assignment. Try using this instead:

```
bool isOverEighteen(const string &s) 
{ // s is in the form DD/MM/YYYY - if it's not, things blow up.  
  int birthday[3], bidx = 0; 

  birthday[0] = 0;
  birthday[1] = 0;
  birthday[2] = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i != s.length(); i++)
  {
    if(s[i] == '/')
    {
      bidx++;
      continue;
    }

    birthday[bidx] = (birthday[bidx] * 10) + (s[i] - '0');
  }

  // now birthday[0] is the day of birth as an integer, 
  // birthday[1] is the month of birth as an integer and
  // birthday[2] is the year of birth as an integer. You 
  // can use them.

  ...
}
```

There are more elegant ways of doing this, and it's not very "C++" but it works, which is an improvement.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to split "string birth;" and a way to convert it to int type.

Comment: @user1860848 You can always just call the c_str() function on your string object.

Comment: @EricFinn even if he did that, it wouldn't work. `isOverEighteen()` is totally broken.

Comment: @NikBougalis Right, but my point is std::string doesn't prevent you from having a char array for functions that require char arrays.

Comment: Well Nik, thats the solution! Thank you all for the support!
about the function, it doesn't work here because it was originally written in italian and I had to translate it and made some errors, like atoi(pdate) or date[2];